# NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
try {
        File file = new File("file4.xls");
        if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
        //   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileSystem);
        //Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet0");
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
        sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("HelloWorld");
        Cell cell = sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Value_1_1");
        fis.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am trying to create simple excel file using java. I am getting above mentioned error.

Comment: Does the file exist? If not, you are creating it yourself, and then it's not an excel file.

Comment: Can you try with Apache POI 3.14? That has improved error messages on some kinds of broken files

Comment: I solved this issue by avoiding use file.createNewFile(). Thanks RealSkeptic

Answer (score 2):

Open the file once. 
Check your file once on click save as. If it is generated from HTML it will show as Web page(*.htm , *.html) below drop down to the file. 
You can save as Excel 97-2003 Workbook (*.xls)  and retry to read from code. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line here:

```
    if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
```

That creates a brand new 0 byte file, which is not a valid Excel file. That's why POI objects.

Also, you're using an old version of Apache POI. Newer ones give a more helpful exception if you're silly enough to ask them to read a zero byte file

Taking account of the [advice on Files vs InputStreams](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), but noting you're doing an in-place write which isn't yet fully supported on an opened File, change your code to be more like:

```
Workbook workbook = null;
File file = new File("file4.xls");
if (!file.exists()) {
   if (file.toString().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
      workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   } else {
      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
   }
} else {
   workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
}
```

That will work for both `.xls` and `.xlsx` files, and avoids your errro

Though you really ought to upgrade your version of Apache POI too...

Comment: Good maners is a must.
You don't need to insult to the person who is posting a question.